# DB comparison tools

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison, compare

Has someone experience with database comparison tools?
Which one you would recommend?

We are currently using "SQLCompare" from Redgate, but I am curious to know if there are better tools on the market.

The main requirement is that they should be able to compare scripts folder against a live database.

Thanks,
Dimi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Compare is pretty good. I've also used SQL Delta which provided better delta scripts. Also if you are a visual studio user, Visual Studio Team System Database Edition is not a bad way to go (includes MSBuild tasks to automate your DB builds and versioning). And VSTS DB (aka data dude) is also free now if you are licensed for VSTS Developer edition.

Answer (score 3):

I work for Innovartis and we make DB Ghost which is something you may want to look at. It can do what you want - compare scripts to a database. It can do this in a single step using the change manager by building and comparing. It is very, very fast. Building the database also gives you the added benefit of dependency checking of the database just in case someone has broken one piece of database code by changing or introducing another. We believe the software offers a way to manage database changes quickly and cost effectively and combined with your source control can give you total control. Like team system but much, much cheaper.

Script, Build, Compare, Upgrade, Create a change script, Deploy, & Copy database function which is free. www.dbghost.com

Comment: I've used DbGhost for 10 years and it's never let me down. The support they provide is second to none

Answer (score 2):

SQL Compare by Redgate is the best tool I've used for db compare.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the [AdeptSQL](http://www.adeptsql.com/) tool for many years and have been very impressed. They have very good support too, and last time I looked they were reasonably priced.

Answer (score 0):

Nice compare tool is inside [TOAD for SQL server](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadsqlserver/toad_sqlserver.htm). It was standalone free application, but now it is only part of full package. But you can try beta version. You can make snapshot of structure and anytime compare live server against snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the [Apex SQL tools](http://www.apexsql.com) - it's always a bit of a toss-up whether I prefer the Red-Gate or the Apex tool for the same job :-)

Answer (score 0):

We can recommend you a reliable [SQL comparison tool](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/) that offer 3 times faster comparison and synchronization of  table data in your SQL Server databases. It's [dbForge Data Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/).

Main advantages:

- Speedier comparison and synchronization of large databases
- Support of native SQL Server backups
- Custom mapping of tables, columns, and schemas
- Multiple options to tune your comparison and synchronization
- Generating comparison and synchronization reports

Plus free 30-day trial and risk-free purchase with 30-day money back guarantee.